# JavaFX WebView does not render visual content on a Dialog<T>

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-9

The following code shows a weird behavior in JDK 9.0.1 (Windows):

### Dialog Snippet

```
Dialog<Void> dialog = new Dialog<>();
WebView webView = new WebView();
dialog.getDialogPane().setContent(webView);
webView.getEngine().load("http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/");
dialog.show();
```

The WebView actually loads, but it does not render the web content to the GUI.

### Proof Snippet

I had the following code (I edited it for simplicity sake)

```
private void loadSite(String url) throws IOException {
    CookieManager cookieManager = new CookieManager();
    CookieHandler.setDefault(cookieManager);
    URI uri = URI.create(url);
    Map<String, List<String>> headers = new HashMap<>();
    CookieHandler.getDefault().put(uri, headers);
    webEngine.getLoadWorker().stateProperty()
        .addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
            System.out.println(newValue);
            if (newValue == Worker.State.SUCCEEDED) {
                System.out.println(cookieManager.getCookieStore().getCookies());
            }
        });
    webEngine.load(url);
}
```

This snippet is used to print cookies from a fully loaded page. The worker reaches State.SUCCEEDED and the cookies get printed out, but the WebView doesn't render the web page.

### Working Snippet

I tried the following snippet and it worked, the WebView actually renders the web page to the GUI:

```
Stage stage = new Stage();
final WebView webView = new WebView();
webView.getEngine().load("http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/");
stage.setScene(new Scene(webView));
stage.show();
```

The Dialog Snippet works with JDK 8 but not JDK 9.

### Side by side comparison

[image: Stage Snippet left, Dialog Snippet Right]
Stage Snippet left, Dialog Snippet Right

### Actual Question

Am I doing something wrong? **why is this happening?** I read some of the JDK 9 changes, but I didn't see anything relatable.

Thanks in advance for any colaboration.

Comment: I'm having the same issue - the crazy thing is that if you drag the cursor over the java 9 version and then click+drag that, you will see the text being dragged. So it is as if it is rendering, but with no color...

Comment: @MichaelLandes interesting. I will take some time later to investigate, but maybe, just maybe, applying/reseting css to the WebView Node or Dialog could hack away the problem.

Comment: @LouizFC I get the same problem when trying to place a WebView in a JavaFX Alert dialog using `getDialogPane().setContent(webView)`... did you fix this? This happened when I switched from Java SDK 8 to SDK 9.

Comment: @Antinous unfortunately I didn't. I will gather some time to investigate but I think it is something that can only be worked around and not exactly fixed.

Comment: @LouizFC I ended up using a TextArea in the end, which is not as good as a WebView visually of course, but works nonetheless.

Comment: @Antinous If you can add depedencies to your project, I suggest you to see https://github.com/FXMisc/RichTextFX

Answer (score 1):

I have similar issue with rendering content into a JfxPanel and it is rendering blank but HTML content can be printed in my java console. (I'm using JxBrowser but they are very similar)

I solved the issue by making the **webEngine rendering Mode from Heavy Weight to Light Weight**.

Essentially Swing/JavaFx components are light weight for the most part, if we stack a heavy weight component inside a light weight component it will have rendering problems. 
Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I have got exactly the same issue. When I show the WebView in another context (e.g. in a TabView (within a Tab)) the HTML-file is shown properly. But when I use

`dialog.getDialogPane().setContent(webView);`

it is not. My code is pretty much the same as the Dialog Snippet above (except the location of the HTML-file) and I cannot figure out the problem.

Not even simple HTML with just one headline is displayed.

Comment: did you fix this in the end? I have the same problem with WebView in a JavaFX Alert dialog. `getDialogPane().setContent(webView)` does not show the WebView...